# Array of moving objects stacking up

Tags: arrays, class, object, processing

My question concerns creating an array of moving objects. The goal is to have each created "symbol" starts at x=200 when created and then moves along the x-axis. This is possible by creating individual objects, though when I try to make them appear in an array they just appear on top of each other (made the balls transparent so you can see them stack). Is there a way to create an array of individual array objects so that this doesn't happen.

```
int numSymbols = 100;
int symbolXPos;
int i;

Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[numSymbols];   

void setup(){
for(int i = 0; i < numSymbols; i++){
   symbols[i] = new Symbol(); 
  }

  size(748,1024);
    }

    void draw(){
  background(255,255,255);
  i++;
  if(i > 10){
symbols[1].addSymbol(i);
  }
  if(i > 100){
symbols[2].addSymbol(i);
  }
  if(i > 200){
symbols[3].addSymbol(i);
  }

}

  int symbolY = 748-2*6-89-180;
  int symbolX = 200; 
  int symbolPos;
  boolean firstLoop = true;
int xSpeed;

class Symbol{

   void addSymbol(int xSpeed){

if(firstLoop == true){
symbolXPos = xSpeed;
firstLoop = false;
}else{

  xSpeed = symbolX + (xSpeed - symbolXPos);    

fill(0,0,0,20);
noStroke();
rect(xSpeed,symbolY, 36, 36, 18);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part that looks strange is that you have these properties that seem related to a Symbol instance, and not to the main scope:

```
int symbolY = 748-2*6-89-180;
  int symbolX = 200; 
  int symbolPos;
  boolean firstLoop = true;
  int xSpeed;
```

perhaps you meant something like this:

```
int numSymbols = 100;
int symbolXPos;
int i;

Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[numSymbols];   

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numSymbols; i++) {
    symbols[i] = new Symbol();
  }

  size(748, 1024);
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  i++;
  if (i > 10) {
    symbols[1].addSymbol(i);
  }
  if (i > 100) {
    symbols[2].iaddSymbol(i);
  }
  if (i > 200) {
    symbols[3].addSymbol(i);
  }
}

class Symbol {
  int symbolY = 748-2*6-89-180;
  int symbolX = 200; 
  int symbolPos;
  boolean firstLoop = true;
  int xSpeed;

  void addSymbol(int xSpeed) {

    if (firstLoop == true) {
      symbolXPos = xSpeed;
      firstLoop = false;
    } else {

      xSpeed = symbolX + (xSpeed - symbolXPos);    

      fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
      noStroke();
      rect(xSpeed, symbolY, 36, 36, 18);
    }
  }
}
```

Even so, it feels like the code is more complex than it should be and there is some confusion regarding classes and objects/instances.

Let's assume you're simply going to move symbols horizontally. You could use a class as simple as this:

```
class Symbol{
  //position
  float x;
  float y;
  //speed
  float speedX;

  void updateAndDraw(){
    //update position
    x += speedX;
    //reset to 0 if out of bounds
    if(x > width) x = 0;
    //draw
    rect(x, y, 8, 8, 18);
  }

}
```

It has an x,y and just a `speedX` for now. The x property is incremented by the speed, and the updated position is used to render the symbol on screen.

Here's a basic sketch using the above class:

```
int numSymbols = 100;
Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[numSymbols];

void setup(){
  size(748, 1024);
  fill(0, 0, 0, 64);
  noStroke();

  for (int i = 0; i < numSymbols; i++) {
    symbols[i] = new Symbol();
    //use different speeds to easily tell the symbols appart
    symbols[i].speedX = 0.01 * (i+1);
    //increment y position so symbols don't overlap
    symbols[i].y = 10 * i;
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < numSymbols; i++) {
    symbols[i].updateAndDraw();
  }
}
class Symbol{
  //position
  float x;
  float y;
  //speed
  float speedX;

  void updateAndDraw(){
    //update position
    x += speedX;
    //reset to 0 if out of bounds
    if(x > width) x = 0;
    //draw
    rect(x, y, 8, 8, 18);
  }

}
```

The key points are:

1. using properties related to a Symbol within the class, not outside (which would mean the global scope)
2. using different positions so Symbol instances don't overlap

Be sure to check out [Daniel Shiffman's Objects tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/), it provides a nice and easy intro to Object Oriented Programming